# Doing an if statement of text.contains and columns of numeric type being matched

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

```
\\ adding the variables

    reference = List.Buffer(#"Reference Tax"[Reference]),
    Cost_center = List.Buffer(#"Reference Tax"[Cost Center]),
    Vendor_Number = List.Buffer(#"Reference Tax"[Vendor Number]),
    Vendor_Name = List.Buffer(#"Reference Tax"[Vendor Name]),


#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Custom1, "Tax_Reference", each if List.Select(
    reference,
    (Taxonomy_Reference)=> Text.Contains([Line Description],Taxonomy_Reference)) and List.Select(
    Vendor_Number,
    (vendornumber)=> Vendor Number=vendornumber and  List.Select(
    Cost_center,
    (costcenter)=> Text.Contains([[Cost Centre]],costcenter)) then "Flagged" else "Not Flagged"),
```

Vendor number is numeric so that's why i put the = sign.

Essentially, if line description matches the Reference (from Reference Tax table) using the text.contains and vendor number is equal to the vendor number (from Reference Tax table ) then i want to bring a specific column from Reference Tax Table. Can i get some guidance on how to correct this?

Comment: Hello - try wrapping Vendor Number in square brackets.

    (vendornumber)=> [Vendor Number] =vendornumber and  List.Select(

Comment: I am getting an error can't convert type list to type logical. Does this mean i can't use an if statement here?

Comment: No, that means one of the statements that should resolve to true/false is instead resolving to a list.  I also see that you have Cost Centre wrapped in double square brackets instead of single square brackets.  Essentially this statement is selecting list elements. In order to return logical (true/false) you will need include a final evaluation statement. Try assigning the list to a variable, like ... "Tax_Reference", each let varList = List.Select( ... costcenter)) in if varList = {} then  then "Not Flagged" else "Flagged", type text )

Comment: Awesome - I'll add this to the answer so you can accept it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to return logical (true/false) you will need include a final evaluation statement. Try assigning the list to a variable, like ... "Tax_Reference", each let varList = List.Select( ... costcenter)) in if varList = {} then then "Not Flagged" else "Flagged", type text )